# Wordpress theme usage rights with GPLv2

Tags: wordpress, licenses

I've been searching for a great looking wordpress theme to use on a small magazine website idea that I had and I've just found one that would be ideal, with lots of blank spaces specifically designed for adverts - But then when I came to download it there was a notice:

```
License: GPLv2 or later. Type: Non-Commercial
```

Does this mean that you can use the theme but not use the advert space? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing because there are 2 pieces of information here that are not intuitive.

First is the license that this theme is distributed under, GLPv2. Short answers is that GPLv2 allows you to modify and distribute as you see fit. You can ready about the specifics here - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

The second piece of information is the type theme - in this case non-commercial. That means that the theme is not being sold. A commercial theme would have some sort of fee involved - site membership, download fee, support subscription, etc.

The license determines how it can be used, and you can pretty much do what every you want under GPLv2.

Answer (score 0):

The licence is GPL 2.0 which you can read here http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

It is for noncommercial use, which means it can't be used for commercial purposes. You can put adverts but not distribute it commercially (noncommercial distribution is outlined in the licence link above).